# Density functional matrix for network analysis

Tags: solid-state-physics, many-body, density-functional-theory, network

I am an archeologist just beginning to venture into the study of crystalline materials, specifically ceramics, to understand how their spatial distribution and formation process can be studied using crystallographic data. So I'm extremely sorry if my question seems odd or absolutely baseless. I would like to approach the problem from the microscopic level so that I can demonstrate the macroscopic trajectory of events as one of the numerous probabilities contained within the microscopic interactions. I would like to use density functional matrices in combination with network theoretical tools to approach my research question. Is such an approach feasible?

P.S. I have only been exposed to the theoretical aspects of such issues but not been fortunate enough to practically understand their intricacies. So if you could please be beginner friendly and considerate with the answers, it would be really helpful.